# Ubuntu 20.04 with ZFS Rpool have hundreds of Cloned filesystems

Tags: 20.04, zfs

I have installed the new Ubuntu 20.04 on my server using the ZFS setup.

All is working well, but I see some strange things.
`zsys-gc` and `zsys-commit` services are marked as failed with this error

```
 level=error msg="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context
 deadline exceeded"
```

My disk used space keeps growing, I had hundreds of snapshots and cloned filesystems in the `rpool`.
I know that `zsys` auto snapshotting is still in development, I don't care much as I can do manually snapshot when I need.
The problem is that I can't delete all this snapshots because are linked to cloned filesytems, and I really don't understand why Ubuntu keeps creating new cloned filesystems.
All this filesystems are under the filesystem `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_093s22/var/lib`
For example:

```
 rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_093s22/var/lib/001e8858fabddf7a79270efe28da048d73a67812a478bba5cbd866a64ebfa2f6
 rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_093s22/var/lib/001e8858fabddf7a79270efe28da048d73a67812a478bba5cbd866a64ebfa2f6-init
```

and so on....

No one of them are mounted atm.

It should be safe to destroy such cloned filesystems?

It's normal that Ubuntu is creating hundreds of sub cloned filesystems in var/lib directory and no one are mounted?

Answer (score 1):

This is not ubuntu but probably you have docker installed which is creating them for you. You should remove the zfs integration (unsure what this brings up by default, their wiki page doesn’t really list the benefits: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/zfs-driver/). A fix of the default ubuntu docker package in the repo in a couple of weeks will create rpool/var/lib/docker so that they are created there, as persistent datasets. (`rpool/var` and `rpool/var/lib` will have canmount=off).

If you remove your containers, from my tests, with `docker rm` (including stopped ones), they will be deleted.

Please file bugs on docker itself so that this is tunable by the user and that they explain what benefits this brings (also changing their default distribution to have a persistent rpool/var/lib).

More info on https://github.com/ubuntu/zsys/issues/102.